# Attribute routing with default root parameter in WebAPI

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an API where all methods need a fixed parameter {customer} :

```
/cust/{customerId}/purchases
/cust/{customerId}/invoices
/cust/{customerId}/whatever*
```

How can I map all controllers to receive this parameter by default in a reusable way like:

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "Default", pattern: "/cust/{customerId:int}/{controller}*"
```

I am using .net core 3.0 with the new .useEndpoints method on Startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an implementation of [`ControllerModelConvention`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.applicationmodels.icontrollermodelconvention?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to custom the attribute route behavior. For more details, see [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/application-model?view=aspnetcore-3.1#sample-modifying-the-controllermodel-description).

For example, suppose you want to combine an attribute route convention (like `/cust/{customerId:int}/[controller]`) with the existing attribute globally, simply create a Convention as below:

```cs
public class FixedCustomIdControllerConvention : IControllerModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(ControllerModel controller)
    {
        var customerRouteModel= new AttributeRouteModel(){
            Template="/cust/{customerId:int}",
        };
        var isApiController= controller.ControllerType.CustomAttributes.Select(c => c.AttributeType)
            .Any(a => a == typeof(ApiControllerAttribute));
        foreach (var selector in controller.Selectors)
        {
            if(!isApiController)
            {
                var oldAttributeRouteModel=selector.AttributeRouteModel;
                var newAttributeRouteModel= oldAttributeRouteModel;
                if(oldAttributeRouteModel != null){
                    newAttributeRouteModel= AttributeRouteModel.CombineAttributeRouteModel(customerRouteModel, oldAttributeRouteModel);
                }
                selector.AttributeRouteModel=newAttributeRouteModel;
            } else{
                // ApiController won't honor the by-convention route
                // so I just replace the template
                var oldTemplate = selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template;
                if(! oldTemplate.StartsWith("/") ){
                    selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template= customerRouteModel.Template + "/" + oldTemplate;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then register it in Startup:

```cs
services.AddControllersWithViews(opts =>{
    opts.Conventions.Add(new FixedCustomIdControllerConvention());
});
```

#### Demo

Suppose we have a `ValuesController`:

```cs
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get(int customerId)
    {
        return Json(new {customerId});
    }

    [HttpPost("opq")]
    public IActionResult Post(int customerId)
    {
        return Json(new {customerId});
    }

    [HttpPost("/rst")]
    public IActionResult PostRst(int customerId)
    {
        return Json(new {customerId});
    }
}
```

After registering the above `FixedCustomIdControllerConvention`, the routing behavior is:

1. The HTTP Request `GET https://localhost:5001/cust/123/values` will match the `Get(int customerId)` method.
2. The HTTP Request `POST https://localhost:5001/cust/123/values/opq` will match the `Post(int customerId)` method
3. Because we intentionally put a leading slash within `/rst`, the global convention is passed by. As a result, the `POST https://localhost:5001/rst` will match the `PostRst(int customerId)` method( with customId=0)

---

In case you're using a controller annotated with `[ApiController]`:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ApiValuesController : ControllerBase
{

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get([FromRoute]int customerId)
    {
        return new JsonResult(new {customerId});
    }

    [HttpPost("opq")]
    public IActionResult Post([FromRoute]int customerId)
    {
        return new JsonResult(new {customerId});
    }

    [HttpPost("/apirst")]
    public IActionResult PostRst([FromRoute]int customerId)
    {
        return new JsonResult(new {customerId});
    }
}
```

You probably need decorate the parameter from routes with `[FromRoute]`.